# how to avoid viewing php output string(5) ",,,,," on the html page

Tags: php, html

I am Developing this website using bootstrap and php, I have almost finished developing it but the php output is viewing in the top left corner. I want know how to remove it from there and make the page look like a normal page.

```
<?php 

require_once'db.php';

$db = new DB();

$products = $db->getAllProducts();

isset($_COOKIE['sids']) == true? var_dump($_COOKIE['sids']):'nothing';

?>
```

This the php code which I have inserted above the header. I am using this code to implement a shopping catalog which fetches the data from the php file.

I have also attached the screenshot of it.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of

```
isset($_COOKIE['sids']) == true? var_dump($_COOKIE['sids']):'nothing';
```

It outputs that text and serves no purpose other than debugging

Comment: can u tell me what is the exact purpose of it as I dont know much about it.

Comment: It just  tells you what the data type and value inside `$_COOKIE['sids']` is or prints "nothing" if it has not been set yet. That's all it does.

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help @john